# Can I use a reverse proxy service to route web requests to some other port than 80 on my home server to avoid breaking my ISP's ToS?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, webserver, terms-of-use

Is there a way to route all requests thru a proxy service, like Amazon Gateway, to specific ports on my home internet?

This will increase security at my home and will allow me to operate with the same internet plan without breaking the ToS.

Comment: Related on ServerFault: [Is it possible for CloudFlare to get content from 8080 and serve it on 80?](https://serverfault.com/questions/843313/is-it-possible-for-cloudflare-to-get-content-from-8080-and-serve-it-on-80)

Comment: I would also recommend you double check your ToS - is it really only saying you can't expose port 80 to the public net, or that they don't want you hosting a web server on your line at all? In which case just using a different port is likely still breaking your ToS.